# Office.Recipients (interface) getAsync returns empty instead of mail adresses

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The "getAsync" function of the office recipient interface returns an empty result even if adresses has been added to the to/cc/bcc field.

When you enter a email address in the to / cc / bcc field and then you open the ScriptLab sample Add-In (Compose Message To), if you click on the "Get who this is to" button, an empty result is returned. The recipients are still not resolved as they should!

[ScriptLab GetAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tn2T.png)

The only way to resolve the recipients is to click on Tab/Space or ";".
When the getAsync is call, all recipients should be resolved automatically.

Comment: Have you tried to save the email first by calling the `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()` method before getting recipients? Does this help?

Comment: Eugene, Thank you for the help! Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync() forced the resolve of the item. It's a good work around, but I think the best fix would be that Outlook automatically resolve all fields after field focus change.

Comment: This is a well-known issue when dealing with the Outlook object model which exists for ages. The issue is not related to web add-ins only, VBA and COM add-ins have the same picture.

Comment: The getAsync function will only return resolved recipients.
please refer to the following link for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563609/outlook-addin-getasync-successful-but-returns-nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook caches values and doesn't propagate changes to the object model until the focus is moved to another field on the UI or the item is saved. This is a known issue when dealing with Outlook.

A possible workaround is to call the `SaveAsync` to get changes saved and then request new values. So, prior to getting recipients in the code you need to call the following method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()
```